# Convert coordinates for San Francisco using pyproj

Tags: python, coordinates, gis, proj

I have a shapefile of San Francisco that I successfully loaded but I need to convert the coordinates to longitude/latitude form. The variables I have are as follows:

w1 = x coordinates
w2 = y coordinates

Currently the coordinates look like this:

```
print(w1[0], w2[0])
6017864.66784 2104744.54451
```

I've tried to convert the points like such:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
inProj = Proj(init='epsg2227')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg4326')
x1, y1 = w1[0], w2[0]
x2, y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
print(x2, y2)
-70.44154167927961 41.036642156063856
```

San Francisco's coordinates are approximately -122 degrees west and 37.7 degrees north. I believe my problem is that my inProj and outProj commands have the wrong epsg but I can't figure out what I should be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned more about pyproj than I had originally intended:

All you need to do is add `preserve_units = True` to your Projection aliases:

```
w1=[1]
w2=[1]
w1[0]=6010936.158609
w2[0]=2090667.302531
from pyproj import Proj, transform
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:2227', preserve_units=True)
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326', preserve_units=True)
x1, y1 = w1[0], w2[0]
x2, y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
print(x2, y2)

[out]: -122.4, 37.8
```

Basically all `preserve_units` does will use local units instead of standard meters.

[here's the git page](http://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/pyproj.Proj-class.html)

[Here is the transform page](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=2227&t_srs=4326&x=6010936.1586090&y=2090667.3025310)

Basically 2227 is in US survey foot units and 4326 is in degrees and it was treating both as meters

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.